# Java Split discards empty array elements

Tags: java, arrays

I have this bit of code, however I get an ArrayIndexOutofBoundException. I realized that the split function removes all empty array elements, but I believe if I add a negative limit, the empty array elements will not be removed. Having said that, inputString[3] is still out of bounds. I know I can just create another String[] array and copy the values from inputString[], then add elements to my new array, but I was wondering if there was a way to just stop the split function from discarding empty array elements.

```
public static String[] getData() {
    String weightHeight = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your weight in pounds \nfollowed by a comma \nfollowed by your height in inches");
    String[] inputString = new String[4];
    inputString = weightHeight.split(",|\\'", -1);
    if(inputString[2]!= null){
        inputString[3] = inputString[1];
    }
    return inputString;
```

Comment: The `new String[4]` is lost, split returns another array.

Comment: Because split function creates a new array. So you predefinding array size to 4 isnt going to achieve anything here. Instead of Null checks I will use inputString.length > 2 checks

Comment: What is the if statement supposed to achieve anyway?

Comment: to check if inputString[2] has a value. It will have a value if the user enters something like 150,5'6 and not have a value if the user enters 150,66.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you. I have created a merge function to merge output of split function into your inputString array.

```
private static void merge(String[] source, String[] dest) {
    for(int i=0; i< dest.length && i< source.length; i++) {
        dest[i] = source[i];
    }
}
public static String[] func(String[] args) {
    String input = "150,5'6";
    String[] inputString = new String[4];
    merge(input.split(",|\\'", -1), inputString);
    if(inputString[2]!= null){
        inputString[3] = inputString[1];
    }

    return inputString;     


}
```